# How can I mount an EXT2 partition under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, compatibility

How can I mount an EXT2 partition under Windows 7? Not under Total Commander, because I'm searching for a solution to "see the partition from the My Computer" icon.

Are there any? A read-only file system would be enough, as I don't really need a writable EXT2 file system under Windows 7 Pro (64bit).

UPDATE: the EXT2 disk is really an USB HDD.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing Drive Between Ubuntu and Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/11766/sharing-drive-between-ubuntu-and-windows-7) -- please see the first answer about sharing an ext2 partition. Also [this](http://superuser.com/questions/85579/ext3-on-windows-7) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/103661/how-to-read-external-usb-hard-drive-formatted-ext3-from-windows-7).

Comment: Run the program in compability mode vista service pack 2, and then as adminstrator

Comment: This answer is not correct.  It makes no sense.  Running it in this compability mode would just cause it to run as if it was running on Vista which behaves EXACTLY like it normally would on Windows 7.

Answer (score 4):

There are several options, but in the long run I prefer having a FAT32 or NTFS partition that I share on a dual boot system.

- [Explore2fs](http://www.chrysocome.net/explore2fs)
- [DiskInternals Linux Reader](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader)
- [Ext2 Installable File System For Windows](http://www.fs-driver.org/index.html)
- [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/)

Some [screenshots](http://www.howtoforge.com/access-linux-partitions-from-windows) are here.

Comment: ext2ifs doesn't work under win7..

Comment: ext2fsd didn't work, win7 gived me an error message: didn't recognized the drive, format?...

Comment: "linux reader" is detected as a virus according to virustotal.com...

Comment: explore2fs is not what i want. i need a solution so that the EXT2 drive could be visible in the "my computer", and not by opening a program..

Comment: @LanceBaynes - Windows does not support EXT2 thus what you want is not possible.

Comment: linux reader worked for me on win7 with ms security essentials as the virus protection

Answer (score -2):

I Googled "mount an ext2 partition under windows 7" (taken directly from your question title) and there were several promising links.

I didn't read any of them, but I noticed Google's description of the first said:

> Note that in Windows Vista/7 you must use “Run as administrator” ...

Does this help?

Comment: no, it doesn't helped me, why would it?

Comment: I thought it might because you asked about *mounting an EXT2 partition in Windows 7*. I don't use Windows myself, so I'm not speaking from experience, just trying to be helpful.

Comment: hoooooooookay :)

Comment: This site exists so that people who ARE experts in one area can help those who aren't. If you don't know the answer, then don't answer the question. You can post a comment if you think you have something to say that isn't an answer.

Edit: it does; it now shows this question.

In general, don't assume somebody can't Google unless you have actual evidence of this. Also, provide links: the site Google gave you may have been helpful (but probably would have been found already if it were), but by now, Google probably gives a different site.